# Reverse String Vowels

Tags: java, string

i was trying to write code to reverse the vowels of string but its not reversing the chars as it should be please check it tell me what i have done wrong :)

```
package stringQuestions;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseVowelsOfSTring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

              String S = sc.nextLine();
              int n = S.length();
              char ch[] = S.toCharArray();
              for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
                 
                  if(ch[i] == 'a' || ch[i] == 'e' || ch[i] == 'i' || ch[i] == 'o' || ch[i] == 'u'
                  || ch[i] == 'A' || ch[i] == 'E' || ch[i] == 'I' || ch[i] == 'O' || ch[i] == 'U'){
                      for(int j = n-1; j>i; j--) {
                  if(ch[j] == 'a' || ch[j] == 'e' || ch[j] == 'i' || ch[j] == 'o' || ch[j] == 'u'
                  || ch[j] == 'A' || ch[j] == 'E' || ch[j] == 'I' || ch[j] == 'O' || ch[j] == 'U') {
                      char temp = ch[j];
                      ch[j] = ch[i];
                      ch[i] = temp;
                      break;
             }
             } 
             } 
             }
                System.out.println(ch);
}
}
```

Comment: give some expected output for some input. your statement isn't clear

Comment: I'd recommend that you put all those `if` statements into a function called `bool isVowel(char c)` and call it like `if (isVowel(char[i]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should store the last char reversed, otherwise you'll keep replacing the same char at the end of the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

          String S = sc.nextLine();
          int n = S.length();
          char ch[] = S.toCharArray();
          int lastReversedChar = n - 1;
          for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {

              if(ch[i] == 'a' || ch[i] == 'e' || ch[i] == 'i' || ch[i] == 'o' || ch[i] == 'u'
              || ch[i] == 'A' || ch[i] == 'E' || ch[i] == 'I' || ch[i] == 'O' || ch[i] == 'U'){
                  for(int j = lastReversedChar; j>i; j--) {
              if(ch[j] == 'a' || ch[j] == 'e' || ch[j] == 'i' || ch[j] == 'o' || ch[j] == 'u'
              || ch[j] == 'A' || ch[j] == 'E' || ch[j] == 'I' || ch[j] == 'O' || ch[j] == 'U') {
                  char temp = ch[j];
                  ch[j] = ch[i];
                  ch[i] = temp;
                  lastReversedChar = j - 1;
                  break;
         }
         } 
         } 
         }
            System.out.println(ch);
```

Comment: Not quite. Set `lastReversedChar` to `j - 1`. https://ideone.com/FQ5Ffe

Comment: thanks you so much for the answer Calculuwhiz and everyone its working ; )